# Where to send questions or concerns about the Overflow?

Tags: discussion, the-overflow

I am asking which (if any) of the many Stack Overflow sites (domains/sub-domains/whatever you call them) is appropriate to post questions or concerns about "the Overflow", Stack Overflow's newsletter.

For example, this morning's (10/17) distribution included an abstract and title regarding a news story about a blind man who sued Domino's Pizza, but no hyperlink. Which site should I (re)post this concern to, if not Meta?

From the email source:

```
A Pac Man clone written in Go (with emojis!) <https://github.com/danicat/pa=
cgo>
github.com
 Learning Go can be tough if you aren't sure how to start. This is a fun=20
little tutorial to build a Pac-Man clone from scratch!

A Ruby gem for building APIs. <https://www.graphiti.dev/guides/> graphiti.d=
ev
 Imagine a blend of REST and GraphQL=E2=80=94the best of both worlds. You c=
an even=20
fetch multiple resources with a single request (shoutout to userel que m'es=
t=20
<https://stackoverflow.com/users/5399745/el-que-mest> for submitting this).=
=20

Supreme Court hands victory to blind man who sued Domino's over site=20
accessibility **<> cnbc.com**
 This case was a huge win for accessibility on the web, and a potential=20
game-changer for how development teams prioritize it in the future.

Learn Kubernetes, Part I, Basics, Deployment and Minikube=20
<https://dev.to/azure/kubernetes-from-the-beginning-part-i-4ifd> dev.to
 If you don't Kuber-get-es Kubernetes, here's a great 5-part series to get =
you=20
up and running with it!
```

I added the double asterisk above in an attempt to bold the area of concern, which apparently failed. Note that the original email source did not have them.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: Didn't know that that even existed. What's the difference between meta.stackoverflow.com and meta.stackexchange.com ? ...Wait, I shouldn't ask questions in a comment... which one of those should I use to ask what the difference is? ... meta.meta.stackexchange?

Comment: meta.stockoverflow.com is solely about SO, meta.stackexchange.com is about all sites in the stackexchange network.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Alright, so now the question is: "is 'The Overflow' part of stackoverflow, or just another distinct member of stack exchange?" Obviously the name is related, and the email from address is `do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email`, which is decidedly inconclusive. Still not sure where it belongs.

Comment: The Overflow is a Stack Overflow thing, not a network thing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the bottom of every email edition of The Overflow there is a [Contact us](https://itr-links.stackoverflow.email/u/click?_t=3603a3d8f3104ca5bd7015a5845f7fb7&_m=7111f4b24ba84e80ae270967d51df051&_e=Y0AVsoI94eAcSQ1p5eWHbkwCUNob1xpWb8UNvgg_C6wVLCCvdAoSvpuI2V4K_6tLq8m86Dl5ZXZXHDm7umrli6-dPcNwEWIyrX5OSPgSAf-s4i87FblP8wKNEDZuOHC_HbXM1buV3y8_jQ525DnmgOwtacqlRskXeewSa0EHEplPwgtFyGDOdhxs6sdoMKonXFEXZ8RVWgaF3Ruk8hwUI6UdW-EBCqGHDnftI-yG-RBpjNrr0yYbDTevjndYgcbJxRC7VFISOax9Jh3OE18rm3fsP1wx1UUvjU5t2iH9FAkIWOm7H4chhyq1knJGYo5dwOHn8W4-t6FYFWXP89z8aIrIj_eq0mV42y4FpNzqMTd02GzYlqoC9hnkmE4c7H1KYu0ugD-zin44ARksmjUXr_DpYNqPdvbGUZJyUmYvufk%3D) link. That goes to a "Support & Feedback" page. The second sentence on that page is:

> To share product feedback on our products, please [visit our community here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

That link is a link to meta.stackoverflow.com.

Additionally, the [blog post introducing the newsletter](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/10/01/introducing-overflow-newsletter-cassidy-williams/) says:

> Send feedback or ideas to theoverflow@stackoverflow.com

That's a `mailto:` link on the page, which we can't use in posts here.

Comment: Meta's category tag system is not really conducive to feedback. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390530/feedback-tag-as-an-addition-to-the-possible-categories.