# Why is The Overflow promoting Universal Basic Income?

Tags: discussion, the-overflow

[The Overflow #56: An engineering argument](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/15/the-overflow-56-an-engineering-argument/) includes a link to a blog post which advocates for Universal Basic Income.

I and many other developers read this newsletter to learn about tech trends and skills. After all, the newsletter itself states

> This newsletter is by developers, for developers, written and curated
> by the Stack Overflow team ...

and is self-described as

> Essays, opinions, and advice on the act of computer programming from
> Stack Overflow.

I suspect there are very few who subscribe to The Overflow to learn philosophies around government programs. So I was quite surprised to see that this link was not only *included* in the newsletter, but was *featured in the subject of the email*: "The Overflow #56: An engineering argument."

There are uncountable resources available for learning theory on government programs, which people can attend to when that is what they seek to do. But this newsletter is not where people go for that, and when the content which subscribers *expect to receive* from The Overflow is diluted, the newsletter loses value.

The fact that the blogger makes a connection in his mind between an engineering concept and the feasibility of a government program does not make engineering (let alone computer programming) the topic of the post.

**Wondering if this is the proper place for this question? I was too! [See this.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390521/8534588)**

Comment: Otherwise... this is far from a "developer's" newsletter, it's a marketing tool.

Comment: It's not a paid promotion. It is in the section "Links from around the web"

Comment: `it's a marketing tool` -- Does anyone really think it's anything else?

Comment: OK, so could someone link to Overflow #56?  I seem to be having some difficulty finding it.

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the email for those who haven't received it yet: https://imgur.com/a/XITO6gN

Comment: Aren't these things posted on https://stackoverflow.blog/?  Or is it like modern TV, where those willing to watch commercials get to see the show first on cable, while those not willing to sit through the commercials have to wait until the next day when it is posted to the streaming service?

Comment: Is the blog post you refer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/07/open-source-has-a-funding-problem/)?

Comment: I'm guessing the emails get sent out in a staggered fashion, and then it probably gets posted to stackoverflow.blog once it's been emailed to everyone.

Comment: @RobertHarvey take a look at the screenshot I linked to

Comment: [This?](https://www.scottsantens.com/engineering-argument-for-unconditional-universal-basic-income-ubi-fault-tolerance-graceful-failure-redundancy)

Comment: Yes that is it. Sorry... thought you were asking about the stack overflow blog post :)

Comment: To be fair, there's a huge gap between "links from around the web [that we found interesting]" and "promoting". Arguments can be interesting to read simply because they are well-posed and relevant, regardless of whether or not you agree with them. I don't see any evidence of promotion or endorsement in The Overflow. The author of the linked article was attempting to make it relevant to engineering disciplines, of which programming is at least sometimes considered to be.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree.  It's just a link; Stack Exchange doesn't even host the material.

Comment: I don't see how this fits SO meta as that blog is not part of SO... Generally all marketing stuff SE is doing is explicitly protected from any comments from community, so the only option would be to contact them directly... Idle chit-chat about something unrelated to SO is cool... but meta is not the place for it .

Comment: @CodyGray You make a fair point about the title. I think the main point still stands though about what subscribers are expecting, and how they derive value from the newsletter. It's been a good newsletter and I think it is in the interest of SO and it's subscribers to stay focused on the content that readers look to the newsletter for.

Comment: I wouldn't even begin to speculate about how people derive value from this newsletter. I've never found any value in it. Why do you think that subscribers would be less likely to expect and/or find value in this than in any other link they've included over the past...uh...55 editions?

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think any speculation is necessary. It is intended to provide value for anybody who finds value in reading "Essays, opinions, and advice on the act of computer programming"

Comment: Yet, you disagree with their editorial choices of an essay/opinion that they thought was related to the act of computer programming.

Comment: That is an accurate description. And I posted this feedback in hopes of helping Stack Overflow in the continuous improvement of the newsletter.

Answer (score 8):

I think it's important to distinguish between content hosted directly by Stack Overflow, Inc., and a link to an offsite resource.  The former is an implied endorsement of the published material (unless, of course, it contains one of those "we don't actually believe what we're saying" disclaimers); the latter is merely "you might find this blog post interesting."

I don't see how a link to a newsletter on another web site constitutes advocacy or endorsement of any kind, especially since the linked material is beyond Stack Overflow's control.

I'm on the record, in no uncertain terms, that Stack Overflow should forever remain apolitical, for what I consider compelling reasons.  Naturally, it's their company, their website; they can do with it whatever they wish, for the same reasons that "I told you so" is a fair retort to the folks complaining about getting kicked off Twitter.

But this isn't like that.  Stack Overflow isn't
"making a statement" by hosting "interesting links from the interwebz."  When they do make an actual statement, you'll know.

Comment: Yes, Stack Overflow can put whatever they want in their newsletter. I'm not saying they can or can't do something. I'm simply saying *Hey Stack, you've got a great service you're providing - a newsletter that compiles useful information relevant to developers, and that's why we love it. But if you start to dilute it with stuff that isn't focused on the techy dev stuff that devs read it for, then it's going to lose its luster.*

Answer (score 3):

> I and many other developers read this newsletter to learn about tech trends and skills

I don't think that statement is correct.

> when the content which subscribers expect to receive from The Overflow is diluted, the newsletter loses value.

Actually, that piece probably has more value than some of the other items in the newsletter... need I mention "ciao Winter Bash 2020"? :-(

> Why is The Overflow promoting Universal Basic Income?

*That's* your problem with that post? Come on, you're nitpicking. I'd be much more annoyed by how commercial company whose core software service/product is closed-source, is telling me how the restrictions in GPL are bad and it shouldn't be regarded as "Open Source".

<sub>The post in question: [Here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/07/open-source-has-a-funding-problem/).</sub>

Comment: Stack Exchange does write a fair bit of open source software, though, mostly MIT licensed, see https://github.com/StackExchange. While they do write closed source software, almost all software they produce I'd expect to be open source is actually open source.

Comment: @ErikA: Fair enough, Edited. But - how much of that software is usable outside the context of the StackExchange network?

Comment: I know Dapper has a fairly large user base, and some of the other projects are also in the thousands of favorites on GitHub. Of course, some are only for SE itself, but certainly not all.